# Asyntask downloading and saving images leads to ANR

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have implmented an Asyntask using which I am trying to download image and save it to sdcard of the phone. OnPostExecute I call the asyntask again , this keeps on always .
But after an hour or so the app starts saying ANR , how should I handle this scenerio.

```
    public class DownloadSavePics extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        Context context;
        String Tag = "DownloadSavePics";
        String res;
        QVSEngine qvsEngine;
        String IID; 
        String url1 = "";
        String deviceId ="";
        String FileName ="";

        /*
         * Pass all data required to log in and handle the result here.
         */

        public DownloadSavePics(Context context,String url1,String deviceId) {
            this.context = context;
            this.deviceId = deviceId;
            this.url1 = url1;
            qvsEngine = new QVSEngine(context,null);        
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() { 
            Log.i(Tag, "inside pre execute");
        }

        /*
         * Do all the network IO and time-consuming parsing in here, this method
         * will be invoked in its own thread, not blocking the UI.
         */

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            /*
             * the background thread calls the method CallService 
             * 
             */
            if (qvsEngine.checkInternetConnection()){   
                CallService();  
            }
            return FileName;        
        }

        public void CallService (){
            /*
             *  downloading the file
             */
            try {
                if(qvsEngine.checkInternetConnection()){
                    /*
                     * requested for connection so set the led1 as amber 
                     */
                    try {
                        URL imgURL = new URL(url1);
                        Log.e(Tag,"Downloading from hotspot "+url1);
                        URLConnection ucon = imgURL.openConnection();
                        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
                        int current = 0;                    
                        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                            baf.append((byte) current);
                        }
/*saving the file in the sdcard
*/                                  
                        String FileName = deviceId.trim()+".jpg";                   
                        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/school/snaps/"+FileName;;
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
                        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                        fos.close();                                    
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e(Tag,""+e);
                    } 
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(Tag,""+e);
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                qvsEngine.database.RunQuery("insert into webcam values (null,'"+FileName+"','0')");
                Log.e(Tag,"webcame table has :  "+ qvsEngine.RunQuery("select count(imgid) from webcam where path ='"+FileName+"'") );      
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(Tag,""+e);
            }   
            new DownloadSavePics(context,url1,deviceId).execute();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What about a stacktrace ?>

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will get "Application Not Responding" because

you are calling

```
 new DownloadSavePics(context,url1,deviceId).execute();
```

in `onPostExecute`, so it will execute the `DownloadSavePics` again and when in reaches to onPostExecute it will receive a call again.... so there is no end.

Contineous call `DownlaodSavePics` call results in `ANR`

Comment: `onPostExecute()` is executed on the UI thread, but the task runs on a worker thread, and it is another instance of `DownloadSavePics` that gets executed. At the 1st sight I do not see references from one `DownloadSavePics` object to another; therefore it should not happen. It is recursion, but not like a recursive call.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 But each every time new instance gets Executed, eventhough previuos one complemetes, i.e if first instance completes, it will reach to onPostExecute and then new instance with needs to execute. and so on.. So it will cause ANR

Comment: I am trying to execute the asyntask again when only the previous task is done that is on postexecute.What could be the other way to solve my problem.

Comment: what's more interesting is what happens if he turns the screen: the activity is re-created, but asynctasks do not end.

Comment: @pragnani: what can be causing ANR is not the endless repetition itself, but [an exception OR checkInternetConnection() returning false] in doInBackground(): that will make the task end (and restart) immediately after it started.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the new instance from a Runnable via runOnUIThread(). And if it does not help, post the logs.

Here's an idea: maybe your task ***fails*** to download data (e.g. WiFi has rotten), and *then* you gen an infinite loop of instantly executed tasks. Try to add sleep(500) (in the worker thread) and see if this helps.

Comment: But my class has nothing to do with the view , I am calling this asyntask to keep downloading the imgaes at the background and save the images in the sdcard. And i cannot apply sleep as my next task should only start once the previous gets completed. As of now the download class is downloading imagaes and saving them and pls tell me solution for this scenerio

Comment: Yes you can: `protected String doInBackground(Void... params) { Thread.sleep(500); ...`

Comment: and I did not say anything about views, I said WiFi, which a kind of internet connection.

Comment: Did you try `runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){ new DownloadSavePics(...).execute();})`? BTW, the arguments listed in parens must be `final`

Comment: and did you manage to get your logs? without the logs you cannot find out what happens in the code

Comment: when it gives the ANR no logs are printed. I tried many times today.

Comment: Add logs showing you when the task has started and finished, and when callService() has started and finished.

Comment: by the way, there's a finite number of times that flash memory may be written to.